# How to add different resolution image in flutter for ios,android and web?

Tags: image, dart, flutter

I am trying to deploy my app on iOS and android. I was going through the following doc https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images which I don't fully understand

What I don't understand is do I need 1x,2x and 3x images according to iOS Human Guidelines https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/ 
and also different densities images for android

Also won't this increase the apk or ipa size at release time as android includes iOS resolution images and vice versa.

I was going through flutter samples and some open source projects of flutter and everyone seems to be using only one image for both iOS and Android.

How do I structure the assets folder for image for iOS and android and include in pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no direct support for different assets per platform, so you would add them only once and the same images would be used for Android and iOS.

Comment: Thats kind of a bummer, but android and iOS are very different and will require different density images, so is there a chance of getting rejected from the App Store. If I add iOS images to my Flutter app, does Flutter takes care of rendering them equally well on Android or Web

Comment: This was no issue so far so I assume Flutter takes care. I mostly targeted only Android.

Comment: There is ongoing work https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/25487 but I assume assets will then be added selectively to the build output to only include what matches the platform.